# Compare a string in an array with each string contained in a file.txt in C

Tags: c

I am learning C and I tried to make a function that could check if a string of an array was equal to one already present in a text file(a collection of items related to the automotive sector).

The text file is structured in this way:

```
codeItem1,nameItem1,productionYear1,price1,quantity1
codeItem2,nameItem2,productionYear2,price2,quantity2
```

etc..

Example:

```
w123,wheel,2021,154,10
```

codeItem = alphabetic character+random number.

To make the comparison I used the `strtok` function in order to separate each data whenever a comma is encountered and then I compared the token with `it[i].codeItem` which is a structure variable that contains the code that must not be already in the file. If the token and the code in the structure match then I will have to start again with the insertion otherwise the code will be valid and I will be able to insert it in the file together with the other data that I will insert later

Here is the function:

```
void inItems(FILE *ptr, item it[], int qt)
{
char* id[MAX];
int i;
char fullcode[MAX];

ptr = fopen("inventario.txt", "a");
if(ptr == NULL)
{
    printf("File not open\n");
    exit(1);
}
else
{

    for(i = 0; i < qt; i++)
    {
        printf("Entry of article number %d\n", i+1);

        codegenerator(it, i, ptr);

        printf("Name?\n");
        scanf("%s", it[i].prodName);

        printf("Production year?\n");
        scanf("%d", &it[i].prodYear);

        printf("Price?\n");
        scanf("%f", &it[i].price);

        printf("Quantity?\n");
        scanf("%d", &it[i].qt);

        fprintf(ptr, "%s,%s,%d,%.2f,%d\n", it[i].codeItem, it[i].prodName, it[i].prodYear, it[i].price, it[i].qt);

    }
    fclose(ptr);
  } 
}


void codegenerator(item it[], int i, FILE *ptr2nd)
{
char fcode;
int scode;
char* temp[MAX];
int check = 0;

printf("Insert category\n");
scanf(" %c", &fcode);
do
{
    ptr2nd = fopen("inventario.txt", "r");
    check = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    scode = rand() % 6;
    sprintf(it[i].codeItem, "%c%d", fcode, scode);

    /*Check if the code has already been entered*/
    while (!feof(ptr2nd))
    {
        if(check == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        int numItems = 0;
        fscanf(ptr2nd, "%s", temp);
        char *token;
        token = strtok(temp, ",");

        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (numItems == 0)
            {
                if(strcmp(token, it[i].codeItem) == 0)
                {
                    check = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = 0;
                }
            }

            numItems++;
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }
}
while(check == 1);

fclose(ptr2nd); }
```

I am having these problems with the program:

1. Often the program blocks when entering the category (the `scanf` after `printf("Insert category\n");`)
2. The file is not filled during the for as soon as it arrives at `fprintf` but is filled at the end of the for loop. I need it filled during the for so that I can check if the code is also repeated in the newly entered string.

Code modified with advice received:

```
void inItems(FILE *ptr, item it[], int qt)
{
char* id[MAX];
int i;
char fullcode[MAX];

ptr = fopen("inventario.txt", "a");
if(ptr == NULL)
{
    printf("File not open\n");
    exit(1);
}

for(i = 0; i < qt; i++)
{
    printf("Entry of article number %d\n", i+1);

    codegenerator(it, i, ptr);

    printf("Name?\n");
    scanf("%s", it[i].prodName);

    printf("Production year?\n");
    scanf("%d", &it[i].prodYear);

    printf("Price?\n");
    scanf("%f", &it[i].price);

    printf("Quantity?\n");
    scanf("%d", &it[i].qt);

    fprintf(ptr, "%s,%s,%d,%.2f,%d\n", it[i].codeItem, it[i].prodName, it[i].prodYear, it[i].price, it[i].qt);

}

fclose(ptr);
}

void codegenerator(item it[], int i, FILE *ptr2nd)
{
char fcode;
int scode;
char* temp[MAX];
int check = 0;

printf("Insert category\n");
scanf(" %c", &fcode);
do
{
    ptr2nd = fopen("inventario.txt", "r");
    check = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    scode = rand() % 6;
    sprintf(it[i].codeItem, "%c%d", fcode, scode);

    /*Check if the code has already been entered*/
    while (fscanf(ptr2nd, "%s", temp) == 1)
    {
        if(check == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        int numItems = 0;
        char *token;
        token = strtok(temp, ",");

        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (numItems == 0)
            {
                if(strcmp(token, it[i].codeItem) == 0)
                {
                    check = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            numItems++;
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }
  fclose(ptr2nd);
}
while(check == 1);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `fclose(ptr2nd);` be *inside* the loop where the file was opened? Also please also see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Instead, use the return value from `fscanf` to control the loop. In fact, you have completely ignored the return value from `scanf` and `fscanf` everywhere, but it is usually essential to validate the input.

Comment: Side note: Both `else` statements are not necessary, due to the preceding `exit` and `break` statements. If the code path when the `if` condition is true never continues past the `if` block, then the `else` is never necessary.

Comment: @Ocram - What do you mean by _the program blocks when entering the category_? Of course the program has to block until _the category_ has been entered. Do you mean the program blocks after entering the category?

Comment: @Armali Yes, I meant after the category was entered.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Ok, thanks for the advice I removed the two else.

Comment: Among other parts of your program, the definition of `item` is missing.

Comment: @Armali No 'item' has been defined but I haven't posted the full code because I was having problems with only these two functions.

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried to fix the code following your advice

Comment: It's nonsense to claim that "No 'item' has been defined" since it is used in your program, and it's illogical to exclude the definition on the grounds you're _having problems with only these two functions_ when `item` is used in those functions.